Next.js build deployment fails on typecheck when using Dockerfile
Im trying to deploy my Next.js application with docker. When running "npm run build" locally on my Windows machine, all works fine.
When using the Dockerfile provided by Vercel though, the build fails on the Linting and checking validity of types ... stage with Failed to compile. In my case the error occurs in this part of the code:
const shortIdBids = {
    bids: bids.map((bid) => ({ // Type error: Parameter 'bid' implicitly has an 'any' type.
      ...bid,
      userId: bid.userId.slice(-5),
    })),
    count: bids.count,
  };

As said before, this happens only when using the Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0" node server.js

I've already tried to use different node alpine version, but nothing worked.
Any help is appreciated.

If you have a type defined for bid, just assign it
bids.map((bid:Bid)=>({}))

@Inder That would have worked, but new problems would pop up after that. I just now figured out the problem was prisma and posted an answer below. Thanks for your help though!

As it's so often the case, you get a solution yourself for a 2h debug 30 min after asking a question on stack overflow. In my case, I am using prisma. I didn't run prisma generate, which broke some type dependencies.
